# PHP preg_replace() on multiple items

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$text = preg_replace('/((\*) (.*?)\n)+/', 'awesome_code_goes_here', $text);
?>
```

I am successfully matching plain-text lists in the format of:

```
* list item 1
* list item 2
```

I'd like to replace it with:

```
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I can't get my head around wrapping `<ul>` and looping through `<li>`s! Can anyone please help?

**EDIT: Solution as answered below...**

My code now reads:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\* (.*?)\n/', '<ul><li>$1</li></ul>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/<\/ul><ul>/', '', $text);
```

That did it!

Comment: You may use [preg_match_all](http://tr.php.net/preg_match_all) to match all items and then rewrite them within ul and li tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to simply replace each list item with `<ul><li>list item X</li></ul>` and then run a second replace which would replace any `</ul><ul>` with nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old post - but it needs a solution. Try this! :)

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[ul\](.*)\[\/ul\]/Usi", "<ul>\\1</ul>", $text);
$text = preg_replace("/\[li\](.*)\[\/li\]/Usi", "<li>\\1</li>", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with regex's, but what you're going to want to do is match the pattern you have and capture it into a backreference by surrounding the desired pattern with ()'s.  You can then place $1 (for the first back reference and so on) in your "awesome code section"

[Regex buddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) has a really, really awesome tutorial on regular expressions if you need more

Comment: I've got $1 etc working for single matches, but I was hoping to wrap output around all matches, then add output around each match.

Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
<?php

$text = <<<TEXT
* item
* item
TEXT;

$html = preg_replace( "/^\\* (.*)$/m", "<li>\\1</li>", $text );

echo '<ul>', $html, '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks! But the list is buried in a huge string